# Using the condition, select the desired columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame I created using pandas and want to create new table based on the original, but filtered based on certain conditions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Y', 'Cat', 'no', 'yes', 6],
    ['Y', 4, 7, 9, 'dog'],
    ['N', 6, 4, 6, 'pig'],
    ['N', 3, 6, 'beer', 8]],
    columns = ('Data', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
)
```

My condition that doesnt work:

```
if (df['Data']=='Y') & (df['Data']=='N'):
    df3=df.loc[:,['Data', 'a', 'b', 'c']]
else:
    df3=df.loc[:,['Data', 'a', 'b']]
```

I want the new table to contain data that matches the following criteria:

If `df.Data` has value 'Y' and 'N', the new table get columns `('Data', 'a', 'b')`

If not, the new table gets columns `('Data', 'a', 'b', 'c')`

```
 Data    a   b
0    Y  Cat  no
1    Y    4   7
2    N    6   4
3    N    3   6

  Data    a   b     c
0    Y  Cat  no   yes
1    Y    4   7     9
2    Y    6   4     6
3    Y    3   6  beer
```

Comment: Your first output has `Y` and `N` but no column `c` while second output has only `Y` but it has column `c`. That differs from your verbal description.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a series with a character rather than checking existence for a single Boolean result. You can, instead, use `pd.Series.any` which returns `True` if any value in a series is `True`:

```
if (df['Data']=='Y').any() & (df['Data']=='N').any():
    # do something
```

An alternative method is to use `pd.DataFrame.drop` with a ternary statement:

```
df = df.drop(['d'] if set(df['Data']) == {'Y', 'N'} else ['c', 'd'], 1)

print(df)

  Data    a   b     c
0    Y  Cat  no   yes
1    Y    4   7     9
2    N    6   4     6
3    N    3   6  beer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if all(df.Data.unique() == ['Y','N']) == True:
    df3 = df[['Data', 'a', 'b', 'c']]
else:
    df3 = df[['Data','a','b']]
```

Comment: While this may work, worth noting this is more lax. For example, 'Y' and 'O' would also satisfy the condition. You can also use `pd.Series.nunique` for this method.